# SCSS nested for loops crashing compiler

Tags: loops, for-loop, compilation, sass

So I have the following code:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  @for $j from 1 through 6 {
    $s: 'h' + $i;
    $ss: 'h' + $j;
    .#{$s}-style {
      @extend #{$s};
    }
    #{$ss}.#{$s}-style {
      @extend #{$s};
    }
  }
}
```

Ignoring the top part that is just so styling exist for the `h` elements.

If I run this the SCSS compiler just dies (or crashes the computer) I have run loops far more excessive than this I cannot figure out why this one cause a crash, has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by your 2nd extend.  Each pass through your inner loop is generating 6 new copies of the h1-h6 selectors and Sass has to extend each and every one of them.  Extends will always perform semi-partial matches (eg. extending `h1` will extend `h1.foo`, `.foo h1 .bar`, `h1:hover`, etc.)

Use a unique extend-only selector instead for your extend purposes:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, %h1, %h2, %h3, %h4, %h5, %h6 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  @for $j from 1 through 6 {
    $s: 'h' + $i;
    $ss: 'h' + $j;
    @debug $s, $ss;
    .#{$s}-style {
      @extend #{$s};
    }
    #{$ss}.#{$s}-style {
      @extend #{'%'}#{$s}; // extend `%hn` instead of `hn`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I should have seen that.